# Swift workaround for protocols comparison

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, generics

I know comparing protocols doesn't make any sense but my situation is dictated by choices and decisions taken before me.
A table view's data source is an array of RowViewModel.

```
protocol RowViewModel {}
```

there's nothing in there (yet) to make it even conform to Equatable.
Then my table has different cells, all of which implement that protocol:

```
func getCells() -> [RowViewModel] {
    var rows = [RowViewModel]()
    rows.append(Cell1ViewModel())
    rows.append(Cell2ViewModel())
    rows.append(Cell3ViewModel())

    return rows
}
```

Cell's view model:

```
class Cell1ViewModel: RowViewModel {
    var cellTitle: String
    ...
}
```

This structure is convenient but it now shoots me in the back because I now need to calculate delta to send specific tableView indexes to insert / delete rows. To calculate delta I need RowViewModel to conform to Equatable, which is possible but seems like a workaround that defies the initial point of using this approach. I'd like to do something like this:

```
let oldList = rows
let newList = getCells()

let deltaAdded = newList.filter { !oldList.contains($0) }.compactMap { newList.firstIndex(of: $0) }
let deltaRemoved = oldList.filter { !newList.contains($0) }.compactMap { oldList.firstIndex(of: $0) }
```

What is the best practice here? Is there a way to write a comparison function for concrete types conforming to the RowViewModel?

Comment: _"defies the initial point of using this approach"_ but the point seems to be that this is a table view that can contain anything. One row can be a row of strings, the next a row of images etc, etc. So a very vague point imo.

Comment: It is convenient to decouple view models from view controller that has no knowledge about cell types. I used this tutorial:
https://medium.com/flawless-app-stories/advanced-ios-tutorial-use-mvvm-to-tackle-complicated-tableview-a2386ee817a9

Comment: You basically have an Any protocol here so you must make some changes to it to be able to compare rows

Comment: If you conform to `Equatable` I guess then you cannot define an array of type `RowViewModel` because of Self right? What if you get rid of the protocol and move to an `enum` with associated cases where the enum itself is `Equatable`?

Comment: @RicoCrescenzio I was thinking about just that.. associated types would then be my specific type?

Comment: With `RowViewModel` being so vague, what is the advantage of using it over `Any`? If you could add some more details as to what kinds of values will be conforming to this protocol, and how the table uses this, we could help you a bit better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I told in comment you would have something like:

```swift
class CellViewModel1: Equatable {

    // classes need explicit equatable conformance.
    static func == (lhs: CellViewModel1, rhs: CellViewModel1) -> Bool {
        // your implementation
        return true
    }

}

enum RowViewModel: Equatable { 
    
    // enum automatically is Equatable as long as all cases have Equatable associated types
    case cell1(CellViewModel1)

}

func test() {
    let oldList = [RowViewModel]()
    let newList = [RowViewModel]()

    let deltaAdded = newList.filter { !oldList.contains($0) }.compactMap { newList.firstIndex(of: $0) }
    let deltaRemoved = oldList.filter { !newList.contains($0) }.compactMap { oldList.firstIndex(of: $0) }
}
```

Notice that both enum and ViewModels must conform to `Equatable`.
Still not 100% sure if this fits your necessities.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I could have the == func inside enum itself, to make it less spread arounD?

Comment: @Async- you don't need any == function in enum because swift is smart enough to create one for you since all associated types will conform to Equatable. You have to define a ≠≠ FOR EACH class, since every class will have different attributes I guess